# Can I turn a profit by tainting the galaxy's medicine supply?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

I'm getting ready to do my obligatory mirror run of KOTOR on the darker side of the Force, and a thought occurs to me:

I understand that if, when dealing with the Firaxis Shark on Manaan, if I choose to kill it by introducing a new toxin to the rift, I'll taint the Kolto supply for the galaxy, resulting in a widespread shortage. More to the point, this causes the *price of medpacs* at vendors through the game to increase, to reflect this 'shortsighted' decision.

Thing is, the game provides more medpacs than I can possibly use. Especially if I harass Jolee enough aboard the Ebon Hawk. So I usually end up selling most of them. If I *hold* my medpacs until *after* finishing Manaan, will the price at which I can sell then to a vendor rise as well? Can I engage in a little casual profiteering from my callous war crimes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've got around to confirm the hypothesis. I've had a save game from when I was about to leave the Jedi Academy, so let's make it the starting point. I used some cheats (namely *turbo*, *revealmap* and *invulnerability*) because I wanted to get this done quickly. None of the cheats affected the results.

**Before** the Kolto crisis, prices for the following items were as follows:

```
                |    Price    |
Item            | Buy  | Sell |
----------------+------+------+
Medpack         | 40   | 10   |
Adv. Medpack    | 80   | 20   |
Antidote Kit    | 49   | 12   |
----------------+------+------+
Repair Kit      | 25   | 6    |
Adrenal Alacrity| 50   | 12   |
Response Package| 1000 | 250  |
```

I tested the non-medpack items because I had them in inventory and are "somehow" related to healing. This is a screenshot of the buying and selling prices for Medpacks, at the first store the player finds, in Manaan.

[image: Buying/Selling Medpacks at Manaan, before Kolto crisis]

As seen by both sources, selling prices in KOTOR are 1:4 of the buying price, being truncated when the selling price isn't an integral.

I've done the "hack passcards" approach and lastly, poisoned The Progenitor, passed the court and was banned from Manaan.

**After** the Kolto crisis has begun, the prices for the former items are as follows:

```
                |    Price    |
Item            | Buy  | Sell |
----------------+------+------+
Medpack         | 120  | 30   |
Adv. Medpack    | 240  | 60   |
Antidote Kit    | 147  | 36   |
----------------+------+------+
Repair Kit      | 25   | 6    |
Adrenal Alacrity| 50   | 12   |
Response Package| 1000 | 250  |
```

[image: Buying/Selling Medpacks at Manaan, after Kolto crisis]

As seen, only *real* healing items get their price **tripled**. I didn't look up at how the items were later distributed across vendors, although I remember reading somewhere that the items would become scarcer as well.

Back to the point. As items get their buying and selling prices tripled, it still makes a loss, when buying healing items *before* the crisis. In this sense, you can't make a profit.

On the other hand, **your profits have now tripled** if all you do is sell the healing items *that you get for free*.

---

UPDATE: By suggestion of LessPop_MoreFizz I went ahead and looked at the prices offered by [Suvam Tam](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Suvam_Tan), which for those that don't know, is at Yavin (which for the XBox version is a bonus content; PC, OSX and iOS is right out of the box) and specializes in some *expert* equipment.

He offers better selling prices than the standard vendor and if you beat him at Pazaak 10 times, he gives you a 20% discount on any item (considering his items are pricey, it's well worth it).

Selling prices with him are 65% of the item's buying price, always. Hence, the prices he offers before and after the crisis are as follows:

```
                |           Price           |
                | B.C. | A.C. | B.C. | A.C. | B.C. - Before crisis
Item            | Buy  | Buy  | Sell | Sell | A.C. - After crisis
----------------+------+------+------+------+
Medpack         | 40   | 120  | 26   | 78   |
Adv. Medpack    | 80   | 240  | 52   | 156  |
Antidote Kit    | 49   | 147  | 31   | 95   |
```

Suvam doesn't sell the medpacks, hence the buy prices are there for comparison. You can see that you can buy medpacks before the crisis and then selling them at Suvam after the crisis has begun will get you a **95% net profit**. You can indeed profit from tainting the galaxy's medicine supply.

Comment: And given that Jolee is going to give me ~100 Life Support Packs... That's quite a profit. Now I just need to look into how Yavin is affected.

Comment: Mind if I ask what do you think will be affected on Yavin? Besides having the saves warmed up (hence I could check), IIRC as Yavin was originally bonus content (for the XBox version, which came earlier), I doubt there would be significant change, save for this.

Comment: Yavin offers substantially above average sell-to-vendor prices - I.e. Pre Kolto-crisis, Suvan Tam buys Medpacs for 26 credits.

Comment: Verified that (because I only thought Suvan Tam gave 20% discounts when you beat him 10 times at Pazaak). Selling prices with him are 65% of the item's buying price, always. So before the crisis, the Medpack, Adv.Med. and Antidote Kit sell for 26, 52 and 31 respectively. After, they sell for 78, 156 and 95.

Comment: Those prices are actually high enough to do straight up arbitrage!

Comment: You are right! How come I didn't notice that? Better update the answer, as one can indeed profit buying and selling medpacks.